# Error while opening VS2010 WPF Project with VS2015

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2010, xaml, visual-studio-2015

I'm having trouble when opening a VS 2010 WPF project whith VS 2015: the XAML designer doesn't load the view and an error occures.

The message error is this one :
https://i.stack.imgur.com/aicMJ.png 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/lkbRq.png

> System.ArgumentNullException Value cannot be null. 
>   Parameter name:
>   remoteValues    at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.Isolation.Remoting.LocalNotifyingEnumerable`2..ctor(IRemoteNotifyingEnumerable`1
>   remoteValues, Func`2 converter)    at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.Isolation.Remoting.LocalDesignerView.Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.IDesignerView.get_RelatedDocumentPaths()
>   at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.IsolatedDesignerService.IsolatedDesignerView.CreateDesignerViewInfo(CancellationToken
>   cancelToken)

If anyone could help me with this problem, thanks.